# Secure certain route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in my routes file:

```
devise_for :users,  :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations",
:sessions => "users/sessions",
:omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
devise_scope :user do
  get 'sign_in', :to => 'users/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
  get 'sign_out', :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
end
```

and now I added:

```
resources :users
```

because I want an admin user to be able to see all the users.

In CanCan I have this:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user
      if user.admin?
        can :manage, :all
      end
      can [:read, :edit, :update], User, :id => user.id
    end
    can [:create], User
  end
end
```

Is this secure enough?  Should I also add a before_filter in the UserController to block calls to the newly created route?  Something like this?  Problem with this is that users can't change their own profile anymore...

```
before_filter :check_rights

private
  def check_rights
    unless current_user.admin
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.  The before_filter is completely correct.

I had added

```
resources :users
```

before the devise part, you need to put it behind that part then users can still alter their own profile but can't go to index for example.